# How to send email from shared serve in laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, serve

When my project is run on localhost mail was perfectly send but when I move my project to shared server mail not send i do change in env file but still not working.

My env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=mail.XXXX.com
MAIL_PORT=465 
MAIL_USERNAME=areeba.XXXX@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=XXXX
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Controller file save data in database and also send mail:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'subject' => 'required',
        'phone_number' => 'string',
        'message' =>    'required',
    ]);

    Mail::send('emails.contact-message',[
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'subject' => $request->subject,
        'phone_number' => $request->phone_number,
        'msg' => $request->message
     ], function($mail) use($request){
         $mail->from($request->email, $request->name);

        $mail->to('areeba.premiotravels@gmail.com')->subject($request- 
     >subject);

    });

    ContactUs ::create($request->all());
    return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message', 'Thank you for your 
   message.');
 }
```

and my form is

```
 <form class="ui form" method="post" action="{{ url('contactsubmit') }}">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="field">
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject">
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <input type="text" name="phone_number" placeholder="Phone Number">
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="10">Any Comment (Optional)</textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <button class="ui button" type="submit">Send</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
```

My Route is:

```
     Route::post('/contactsubmit',[
     'uses' => 'ContactUsController@store',
     'as' => 'contact.store'
     ]);
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then edit your question

Answer (score 0):

After moved on shared server you neeed clear cache:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

then you need start queue if you use it